'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style
Cell In[2], line 6
plot(df['Return'], anomaly=anomalies, ts_linewidth=1,

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\adtk\visualization_visualization.py:201 in plot
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:139 in use
raise OSError(

OSError: 'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in style.available)

from adtk.detector import InterQuartileRangeAD
iqr_ad = InterQuartileRangeAD(c=1.5)
anomalies = iqr_ad.fit_detect(df['Return'])

from adtk.visualization import plot
plot(df['Return'], anomaly=anomalies, ts_linewidth=1,
ts_markersize=3, anomaly_markersize=5,
anomaly_color='red', anomaly_tag="marker");


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
